# How to add elements to an array inside a subscribe valueChanges(Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How can I get the values from a reactive form and set them into an array if the form is valid? In my application I have a dynamic form with different forms that appears dynamic.

```
getFormval(){
  let arr = [];
  this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(400)
    )
      .subscribe(_ => {
        if (this.form.valid) {
        // i would like to add form values to this arr array
         arr.push(this.form.value);
        }
      })
    // i want to get arr with all the values here
    console.log(arr);
 }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your code seems to be doing what you want it to do.

Comment: The console log is outside of the subscription so is therefore running first and showing you empty array. Move the console log under the line you push

Comment: it's a dynamic form, when i checked an input, it should appear a form, when i unchecked it will disapear, so i thought about this solution, to put them into an array, the values from those forms, and to get the values from that array to save them

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pitfall for beginners when dealing with observables. Walking through the code posted...

```
getFormval(){
  // the array is declared here
  let arr = [];
  // the subscription is declared here. 
  // declaring a subscription does not immediately update the arr
  // what happens inside the subscription occurs outside this function.
  this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      // ignore any changes until 400ms have passed since the last change.
      debounceTime(400)
    )
      .subscribe(_ => {
        if (this.form.valid) {
         // the array is updated after the line below runs
         arr.push(this.form.value);
        }
      })
    // the array is still [] here because this executes immediately
    //   after the subscription is declared. 
    console.log(arr);
 }
```

So assuming a value change occurs immediately after the subscription is initiated, it's going to be a minimum of 400 ms before you ever have a value in `arr`. By that time, this function has completed and logged `[]` for `arr`.

Without knowing more about `arr`'s uses, I can't tell you exactly what to do with `arr`, but I can tell you that if you log `arr` in the `subscribe` block, you will see values in it (provided the `valid` condition in your `if` statement is met)

A common pattern is to store a value as a response to valueChanges, and display that value in the html would look something like this:

```html
<!-- myComponent.template.html -->
<div *ngFor="let val of arr">
{{val | json}}
</div>
```

```
// myComponent.component.ts

// Declare an `arr` to store the history of the form
arr: myFormType[] = []
ngOnInit() {
  myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val: myFormType) => {
    // As the changes occur, they are pushed to the component's `arr` property
    this.arr.push(val)
  }
}
```

Btw, the argument for `subscribe` in this case is a function of the value of the form, so you could write

```
....subscribe(value) => {
  if(this.form.valid) {
    arr.push(value)
  }
}
```